# Print HTML files within eachother with PHP

Tags: php, html

I am currently working on a project and I would like to print different HTML pages depending on the selection of the user.
Since all pages share the same sidebar and navigation bar I thought I could export them into a different file and always read/show them while also reading the different subsites and showing them.

Here is a little example of the code:

```
$decision = (isset($_GET["site"])?$_GET["site"]:"default");
switch ($decision) {
    case "login":
        readfile("login.html");
        break;

    case "register":
        if($isAdmin){
        readfile("register.html");
        }
        break;
    default: // Prints the dashboard by default
        /* #region To be removed (exists for testing only) */
        //readfile("register.html");
        /* #endregion */

        readfile("dashboard.html");
        break;
```

And since I don't know how I would succeed in showing to pages at the same time which are interconnected I am asking you and I was also wondering if I could send the page information by post and not only by get.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using `include_once` instead of `readfile`

Comment: your question is a bit unclear, what exactly does not work as expected?

Comment: @NikhilGoyal just tried it and it displays them underneath each other

Comment: @jibsteroos lets take YouTube for example. You always have the sidebar on the left and the search field on top and I would like to achieve the same on my site while having the sidebar and "search field" separated from the content of the different pages

Comment: so, traditionally a way to achieve that (without a CMS or other framework) would be to have something like a "header.php" (and maybe "sidebar.php" if needed separately) which includes the contents you want to display on all the other pages. Then on each other page (e.g. page1.php, page2.php) you put `include "header.php"` at the top of the script, and it adds the header content into the page being loaded. Probably makes sense to use a footer.php as well to close the HTML document

Comment: @ADyson Thanks I didnt even think about that, I will try that ASAP

Comment: You can split your content over different `.php` files to build your view, as explained by @ADyson. It might be interesting to check out [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) as it does a lot of heavy lifting for you (CSS, js, responsive grids).

Comment: @jibsteroos I am already working with a bootstrap template and I think I have figured it out now.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my problem was to split my content into several different files and just arrange it in the correct order (suggested by @Adyson)

```
include_once("header.html");
switch ($decision) {
    case default:
        include_once("login.html");
        break;
}
include_once("footer.html");
```